# onResponse method of Android Volley is not executed

Tags: android, json, rest, http, android-volley

I am using Volley for networking and connect to my REST API. The following code shows the onCreate method of my MainActivity. Here I want to make a GET request to my url and receive the JSON information. But it's not working. I made different debug points all over the code. The last thing which is executed is the initialization of the `arrReq`. onResponse and onErrorResponse are not executed and I don't know what is the matter.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupToolBar();
    setupPagerAdapter();
    setupFloatingButton();
    getDeviceId();

    JsonArrayRequest arrReq = new JsonArrayRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, "http://localhost:8888/api/entities", null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    // Check the length of our response (to see if there are any entities)
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        // There are entities so let's loop through them all.
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                // Get each entity
                                JSONObject jsonObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String locData = jsonObj.get("entity").toString();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // If there is an error then output this to the logs.
                                Log.e("Volley", "Invalid JSON Object.");
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        // There aren't any entities. So do nothing!
                    }

                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // If there a HTTP error then add a note to our list.
                    Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
}
```

When I execute the url in my browser on my device the JSON code is received:

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "data":[
      {
         "entity":"(17,)"
      },
      {
         "entity":"(21,)"
      },
      {
         "entity":"(201,)"
      }
   ],
   "message":"Retrieved entities"
}
```

The log does not show any error.

Comment: did you log response in onResponse?

Comment: Yes I did but response is not created because onResponse has been not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. The problem was that I get a `JSONObject` as response but instanciated a `JSONArrayRequest`. When I change that into a `JSONObjectRequest` it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest (Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            if (!response.equals(null)) {

                Log.e("Your Array Response", response);
            } else {
                Log.e("Your Array Response", "Data Null");
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("error is ", "" + error);
        }
    }) {

        //This is for Headers If You Needed
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
           // params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
           // params.put("Authorization", "bearer  " + token);
            return params;
        }

        //Pass Your Parameters here
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            /*params.put("User", UserName);
            params.put("Pass", PassWord);*/
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    queue.add(request);
```

Try this one

Comment: When I execute it like that I get a constructor error because of the `Response.Listener<String>` which is not allowed. The instanciation of the request looks now like this `JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest (url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() { ...` There is no error anymore but I have the same problem that all the logs in the onResponse and onErrorResponse method are skipped. The next executed debug point is the content of the getHeaders() method.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a permission issue,
did you add your manifest.xml file the following code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```